# Anime movie (2000-2015?) that was about a girl who lived in a ufo with rainbow lights

Tags: story-identification, anime

I want to know the title of an anime movie that was about a girl who lived in a ufo. I think the movie is from 2000 to 2015, or it might be a little older. I remember that the ufo had rainbow lights. I think its graphics were like *From Up on Poppy Hill*. The movie had feelings of nostalgia, and sadness with adventure.

Comment: What sort of UFO are we talking about here? A flying saucer? Did the girl look like a regular human, or was she obviously alien in some way? Was she alone in the UFO? And was the UFO mostly in deep space, or on or near a planet? If it was on or near a planet, was it Earth?

Comment: Do you remember anything else? Like about aliens or plot?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.